# Download tfds.load dataset as jpgs to local disk

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I want to download the full cats and dogs dataset to my pc and have the actual jpg files. I could download it directly from e.g. Microsoft, however I would like to use the tfds.load dataset function.

When I try:

```
(raw_train, raw_validation, raw_test), metadata = tfds.load(
    'cats_vs_dogs',
    split=['train[:80%]', 'train[80%:90%]', 'train[90%:]'],
    with_info=True,
    as_supervised=True,
    data_dir=r'D:\TFProjects\catsdogscompl')
```

It does download something, however these are TFRECORD files, not jpg. How can I get the actual jpgs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TFDS actually returns tf.data.Dataset. As mentioned on the main page

> All datasets are exposed as tf.data.Datasets , enabling easy-to-use and high-performance input pipelines.

But you can actually load your dataset and save it manually in jpeg.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
from uuid import uuid1
import os
import warnings

(raw_train, raw_validation, raw_test), metadata = tfds.load(
    'cats_vs_dogs',
    split=['train[:80%]', 'train[80%:90%]', 'train[90%:]'],
    with_info=True,
    data_dir=r'D:\TFProjects\catsdogscompl')

def save_dataset_as_jpegs(dataset, path,):
    """

    saves every image to the 'path' using random name + target

    :param dataset: dataset you want to save
    :param path: where you want to store it
    :param metadata: metadata from dataset. required to get class names.
    :return: Nothing. Just saves the dataset as jpegs.
    """

    for obj in dataset:
        im, name = obj['image'], obj['image/filename']
        serialized_im = tf.image.encode_jpeg(im)

        path_and_name = os.path.join(path, name.numpy().decode())
        tf.io.write_file(path_and_name, serialized_im)

save_dataset_as_jpegs(raw_train, 'jpegs_train/')
save_dataset_as_jpegs(raw_validation, 'jpegs_validation/')
save_dataset_as_jpegs(raw_test, 'jpegs_test/')
```

This code saves raw_test dataset to folder jpegs_test.

Comment: l4morak Thanks for your helpful post, only problem is that I need to basically get the labels into this somehow. So with the random I cannot know anymore what is inside. So I would like to be able to distinguish it, in order to copy the files. So like cats and dogs, but not only limited to this example, also in case there are more than just 2 classes. So this information must be in the dataset, I think/expect.

Comment: @StatTistician if you mean that it should actually save class - it does. Name has the following format: random string + "_" + target_class + ".jpeg". So, random uuid is needed to make sure that every image of the same class is saved under different names. But the target is also saved. P.S. you can slightly change it to save different classes to different folders.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. So it stores everything in one folder with the label in it? Is it possible to put the label first in the name (so that I can sort according to it) and what happens if there are more than 2 classes? Does this code still work? So like Dog_1.jpg Dog_2.jpg Cat_1.jpg Cat_2.jpg Horse_1.jpg Horse_2.jpg (I don't care about the numbers)?

Comment: @StatTistician I changed it. Now this code creates separate folders for each class presented in dataset.

Comment: @StatTistician Yes, it just adds a class name. No matter how many of them are presented. P. S. New version saves each class in it's own folder, but it can hold any amount of classes too.

Comment: Thanks for the update. However, it does not work. The folders don't have the labels in it, neither the files. The folders are named "0" and "1" and the files are named completely arbitrary, like "1a68fbd8-c2c0-11ea-870b-80fa5b0259bc.jp". I need the labels at least in the folder names. Like Cats, Dogs and Horses. At least this. Otherwise I cannot know what Cat is and what Dog or Horse is (without actually manually looking into the files).

Comment: Furthermore the resulting images are not complete. So when I check the result I can see that it does not work, as not all of the images are in the folders. I know that in the original dataset are 23,262 files. In the folders are just 1.163 each.

Comment: @StatTistician 1) I added functionality to extract information about class names from metadata. 2) Are you sure you not just copied the code? You are probably saving only a piece of the dataset. (raw_test, as I mentioned). You also need to save raw_train and raw_validation, this function gives you this opportunity.

Comment: I am just checking your new solution. There is the message "Corrupt JPEG data: 214 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd9". This is likely, because images are corrupted in the original data. Is there a way to get the filenames of those which could not be copied? In general, is it possible to not have arbitrary filenames, but the original ones? The originals do have a number, like 10000.jpg.

Comment: Plus error message Warning: unknown JFIF revision number 0.00

Comment: @StatTistician I discovered that this warnings are raised by the TFDS dataset. When you iterate over it you can get this errors.  And if you look inside the metadata it says "There are 1738 corrupted images that are dropped". I think that when you iterate it just drops them at all without any problems with saved images.

Comment: Ok, thanks for this. Last question: Is it possible to get the original filenames? So not arbitrary ones, this would be quite important for me.

Comment: @StatTistician I will update code in a couple of minutes. Notice that I changed tfds loading code too (I removed string as_supervised=True since I need to get a field that has been deleted).

Comment: Thanks for your update, however I need it with supervised true. So in order to get it, afterwards I call it again? (raw_train, raw_validation, raw_test), metadata = ... and so on. This would be a solution right.